# How can I make Perl functions that use $_ by default?

Tags: perl

I have an array and a simple function that trims white spaces:

```
my @ar=("bla ", "ha  1")
sub trim { my $a = shift; $a =~ s/\s+$//; $a}
```

Now, I want to apply this to an array with the *map* function. Why can't I do this by just giving the function name like one would do with built-in functions?

For example, you can do

```
print map(length, @ar)
```

But you can't do

```
print map(trim, @ar)
```

You have to do something like:

```
print map {trim($_)} @ar
print map(trim($_), @ar)
```

Comment: In these sorts of situations, I ask myself "Do I really care if I have to pass it as an argument?" The answer is usually no. There are better things to care about. :)

Comment: @brian - you're right - I was just wondering why the behavior is different

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using 5.10 or later, you can specify `_` as the [prototype](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes) for `trim`. If you are using earlier versions, use [Axeman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829751/passing-functions-to-map-in-perl/1830571#1830571):

> As the last character of a prototype, or just before a semicolon, you can use `_`  in place of `$` : if this argument is not provided, `$_`  will be used instead.

```
use strict; use warnings;

my @x = ("bla ", "ha  1");

sub trim(_) { my ($x) = @_; $x =~ s!\s+$!!; $x }

print map trim, @x;
```

Incidentally, don't use `$a` and `$b` outside of a `sort` comparator: They are immune from `strict` checking.

However, I prefer not to use prototypes for functions I write mainly because their use makes it harder to mentally parse the code. So, I would prefer using:

```
map trim($_), @x;
```

See also [perldoc perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes):

> This is all very powerful, of course, and should be used only in moderation to make the world a better place.

Comment: Does the `_` prototype do anything that `my $x = @_ ? shift : $_` wouldn't?

Comment: @Michael Carman: I do not think so. However, if `trim` is going to operate on `$_` if no argument is supplied, I would prefer to use a prototype rather than adding extra logic to `trim`. Above all, I would prefer neither, and just use `map trim($_), @x`.

Comment: @Michael Carman: yes, it works with a lexical $_ in the caller

Comment: Note that the _ prototype is new with 5.10

Comment: Lexical $_ is also new with 5.10 :)

Comment: @ysth: Thanks, I had forgotten about lexical `$_`. I don't get to use the new features nearly enough. It occurred to me that using the `_` prototype would also allow in-place modification (like `chomp`) without needing to write extra code. (i.e. you could rely on aliasing)

Comment: In sub trim(_) { s!\s+$!! for @_; @_ }, @_ is an alias for the original variables, so you are actually modifying the variables passed in.

Comment: @runrig **Arrgh!** Changed it to mimic the OP's function which operated only on the first argument. Thank you.

Comment: I am on 5.8 so this doesn't work for me but sounds like this is the way to do it - thanks.

Comment: @hobbs: That was [reverted after Perl 5.24](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar) (some time after 2016-05-09): *"...between perl v5.10.0 and v5.24.0, it could be used lexically by writing my $_. Making $_ refer to the global $_ in the same scope was then possible with our $_. This experimental feature was removed and is now a fatal error, but you may encounter it in older code."*

Comment: @PeterMortensen very true. I think it broke things in some odd ways. So, the `_` prototype is no longer *needed* for correctness, but it's still kind of nice.

Answer (score 7):

The prototype that [Sinan talks about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829751/how-can-i-make-perl-functions-that-use-by-default/1829820#1829820) is the best current way. But for earlier versions, there is still the old standby:

```
sub trim {
    # v-- Here's the quick way to do it.
    my $str = @_ ? $_[0] : $_;
    # That was it.

    $str =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//;
    return $str;
 }
```

Of course, I have a `trim` function with more features and handles more arguments and list context, but it doesn't demonstrate the concept as well. The ternary expression is a quick way to do what the '_' prototype character now does.

Comment: Really good answer since I am on 5.8 - thanks *upvote*; I had to accept Sinan's as a best practice one though - I wish I could accept both.

Answer (score 3):

My favorite way to optionally use `$_` without needing 5.10+ is as follows:

```
sub trim {
    my ($s) = (@_, $_);
    $s =~ s/\s+$//;
    $s
}
```

This assigns the first element of `@_` to `$s` if there is one. Otherwise it uses `$_`.

Answer (score -8):

Many Perl built-in functions operate on $_ if given no arguments.

If your function did the same, it would work:

```
my @ar = ("bla ", "ha  1");
sub trim { my $s = @_ ? $_[0] : $_; $s =~ s/\s+$//; $s}
print map(trim, @ar), "\n";
```

And yes, Perl is kind of gross.

Comment: You would not have to jump through those hoops if you supply the appropriate prototype for `trim`.

Comment: Don't use `$a` outside of a sort comparator. No need for `scalar` in the conditional operator: `@_ ? $_[0] : $_`.

Comment: I think I'll be using python for my next scripting project :)  However, list vs. scalar context is a feature of Perl I enjoy.

Comment: @wrang-wrang: Feel free to ignore features of Perl you do not like. However, if you are answering a Perl question, statements like *Perl is gross* and *I'll use python* are a little annoying.

Comment: Your code wouldn't look as gross if you added a bit of whitespace.

Comment: It's not necessary, except for the poor humans trying to read it and who would otherwise label it "gross". :)

Comment: Mine is the first correct answer.  Keep punishing me, language zealots ;)  You're winning!

Comment: @wrang-wrang: The only zealotry demonstrated in this discussion is coming from you

Comment: Oh, snap!  Sadly, I'm still using perl for quick stuff, because I know it and am too lazy to switch.